# Pass variables between phps

Tags: php, facebook

I am currently working on a facebook app, and in my index.php I have my `$facebook` `$loginURL` and other common variables. Now I also have a "likes.php" file, and I need some of the variables from my index.php.
 How can this be done? I am a newbie, so sorry if it's a silly question

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert please don't link to W3Schools and especially not to answer PHP questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include(), include_once(), require() or require_once() your "likes.php" from your "index.php", then you have access to all the variables from index.php (from the scope where you have included the file). 
But it is probably better to create a class "Likes" and pass the variables to its constructor.

[PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) says: "When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope. "